# What did the Community user edit?

Tags: discussion

The *Community* user edited the question [Does "spot inspection" make sense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/327529/142322):

[image]

However, the question itself has no edit trail:

[image]

My question is: what did the Community user edit, and where is the edit trail?

Notes:

1. I understand that the Community user isn't a real user, but they should still leave an audit trail when an edit is claimed.
2. The edit claimed by the system was done months after the question was asked, so it wasn't a 'recent post' masking of the editing, even if such were possible for a *Community* edit.
3. It wasn't an edit of the answer - there's only one answer to the 'spot inspection' question (*disclaimer: I supplied the answer*), but the answer wasn't edited either.

Comment: Why do you think there was an edit? It might have been just the bumping mechanism.

Comment: @Helmar Because it said on the main page, "*modified* 12 mins ago Community ..." (emphasis mine - *cf* first picture above). I took *modified* to mean *edited*.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the community bump counts as modification. If there is an edit trail those bumps are in there. The bump itself however does not enable us to see that trail.

Comment: See here: [Anomalous community user activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43015/anomalous-community-user-activity), [Please do not “lie” that the Community user “modified” the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247392)

Comment: After a little digging, I found this gem about how to access public timelines (see tchrist's answer) and other easter eggs - [List of unlinked pages on Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76566/list-of-unlinked-pages-on-stack-exchange-sites). (*Unlinked* used in the sense of *undocumented*.)

Comment: @Lawrence neat find. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was no edit. Our beloved Communibot has bumped the post as shown [here in the public timeline](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/327529/timeline) for that post:

[image: public timeline]

Comment: That is a neat feature, did not know that.